# Connect to Exchange Mail on Linux

Tags: linux, email, microsoft-outlook, exchange, email-client

Within our workplace, we rely on Microsoft Exchange for email services. I have a problem with the connecting to the Exchange Server using a Linux device, because we have the EWS (Exchange Web Service) closed (for security reasons). Is there any free client or solution for this problem?

We are using Linux computers (with Kubuntu) and we already tried Evolution (which has only Exchange Web Service) and Thunderbird, but both didn't work.

Comment: IMAP is also an option, I think.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, Outlook on the web (https://mail.domain.com/owa) would be the easiest option if an email application is not necessary.

Using Thunderbrid with IMAP or POP to connect should also work for you.

If it is an on-premises Exchange server, make sure you have POP3 and IMAP4 service enabled (disabled by default) on Exchange.

Following this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients/pop3-and-imap4/configure-pop3?view=exchserver-2019

Comment: We have closed all services/ports for public internet access within the company. While internally we can access mail.domain.com/owa, external access is restricted. Currently, all account connections are handled through Exchange, as depicted in the image ( [example](https://help.ovhcloud.com/web_cloud-email_and_collaborative_solutions-microsoft_exchange-how_to_configure_outlook_2016-images-config-outlook-exchange02.png) ).

Exchange is also enabled on the public network, allowing employees to log in from home using the Outlook application. Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you mean external web access is restricted, while external users can connect via Outlook (Exchange mode)? If yes, IMAP or POP may be the only option left if EWS is also blocked. Or look for other applications which supports using MAPI to connect to Exchange.

Comment: Ports 80 and 443 are closed to the mail.domain.com connection to the public Internet. I think we are going to give up. Thanks anyway.